# How to BulkWrite\UpdateMany with Go driver for MongoDB

Tags: go, mongo-go

I'm migrating from mgo driver, and my function looks like this:

```
queue := collection.Bulk()
for j := range changes {
    ..
    queue.Update(doc, update)
}
saveResult, err := queue.Run()
```

This makes some `$push` and `$set` updates to a single document in a loop. 
How should I do this with the official driver ? Is it `collection.BulkWrite()` or `collection.UpdateMany()` ? Documentation is so vague, I'm lost on how use them both and what's the difference. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your use case, you would use `collection.BulkWrite`. You can find examples of how to use `go-mongo-driver` in the [examples directory](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/tree/master/examples/documentation_examples) of the repository.

`collection.UpdateMany()` will update multiple documents in the collection using the same update filter and modifications. There is a lot more documentation in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) of the mongo shell equivalent. Example:

```
result, err := coll.UpdateMany(
    context.Background(),
    bson.NewDocument(
        bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements("qty",
            bson.EC.Int32("$lt", 50),
        ),
    ),
    bson.NewDocument(
        bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements("$set",
            bson.EC.String("size.uom", "cm"),
            bson.EC.String("status", "P"),
        ),
            bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements("$currentDate",
            bson.EC.Boolean("lastModified", true),
        ),
    ),
)
```

`collection.BulkWrite()` will perform a set of [bulk write operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/). The BulkWrite API was only [introduced](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/commit/4cb519e8e22f6c951c9f1c521296966efb224e49) a couple of days ago for the go driver. There are little examples, however you can always check the tests
 files. Example:

```
var operations []mongo.WriteModel

operation := mongo.NewUpdateOneModel()
operation.Filter(bson.NewDocument(
    bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements("qty",
        bson.EC.Int32("$lt", 50),
    ),
))
operation.Update(bson.NewDocument(
    bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements("$set",
        bson.EC.String("size.uom", "cm"),
        bson.EC.String("status", "P"),
    ),
    bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements("$currentDate",
        bson.EC.Boolean("lastModified", true),
    ),
))

operations = append(operations, operation)

result, err := coll.BulkWrite(
    context.Background(),
    operations,
)
```

Comment: Many, many thanx! Looks like I decided to migrate the day it becomes possible. Without knowing it)